# Trying to animate a progress bar using Jquery 1.7.2 version.Not working

Tags: jquery, progress

Here a fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/u9u4A/. When I change to Jquery 1.7.2, It does not work. But working in 1.9.2 version. Why its happening. Please help.

Comment: Please post your code in the question. If JSFiddle goes down (as it frequently does) your question will be unanswerable.

Comment: It worked. I added the progressbar-ui.js in my project.Dont know abt Jsfiddle.Thanks any way.